# Keep particles from fluid simulation in render?

Tags: rendering, fluid-simulation

When I bake a mantaflow fluid simulation, Blender displays it as colored particles before the mesh is baked. Is there a way to keep these particles without baking a mesh and have them in the final render?

Answer (score 1):

You can sort of do that, using the viewport render:

1) Disable all overlays and set the view mode to rendered:

[image]

2) In the domain's material settings panel, set the Blend Mode to Alpha blend and make sure Show Backface is checked:

[image]

3) Change the domain's material to Transparent BSDF:

[image]

4) If you don't want to see the viewport's background, check the transparent option in the render tab, Film panel:

[image]

5) In the viewport, go to the View menu, and make a viewport render:

[image]

And here's the result:

[image]

You can use this in compositing if you need it to see it in your full feature render. Though I can't think of a way to make it look not overlayed on top or bellow.

[image]